# How to allow Apache to display content from other directories than document root?

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache version `2.4.29-1` in Manjaro Linux. The document root is `/srv/http` where apache properly displays files. But I don't like the idea of coding into the root user's directory of my system, so I want to keep the code in `/home/aditya/Prog/PHP`

I have set apache to access the directory by adding following lines into `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
<Directory /home/aditya/Prog/PHP>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also, I have added a link to this directory in `/srv/http`

```
sudo ln -s /home/aditya/Prog/PHP/ PHP     #in /srv/http
```

But when I try to access `localhost/PHP`, I get

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) PHP/7.2.3
```

The permissions of `/home/aditya/Prog/PHP` and the test file inside are

```
drwxrwxrwx   PHP
-rwxrwxrwx   test.php
```

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Please check my answer. It will resolve your problem.

Comment: Same here. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change the `DocumentRoot` setting in your `httpd.conf` file.

Look for `DocumentRoot` and set the path to /your/path/to/project.

Apache2 site specific config files are kept in /etc/apache2/sites-available/. If you only want to apply config settings for a specific site.